# Is there any meaning associated with probability density of multivariate normal distribution along a line

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, normal-distribution

Given a probability distribution: 
$$P(\pmb r(t); \pmb\mu, \Sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n |\Sigma|}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\pmb r(t) - \pmb\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\pmb r(t) - \pmb\mu))$$
$$\pmb r(t) = \pmb \mu_0 + t\pmb{\hat{u}}$$
where $\pmb{\hat{u}}$ is a unit vector, I wonder what kind of distribution is this. Is this still a normal distribution? If it is, what is its mean and standard deviation?

I have been trying to work out the case where $\pmb\mu_0 = \pmb\mu$, but to no avail:

\begin{align*}
P(\pmb y = t\pmb{\hat{u}} + \pmb\mu) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2} |\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp \left( -\frac{t^2}{2} \pmb{\hat{u}}^T \Sigma^{-1} \pmb{\hat{u}} \right)
\end{align*}

I tried to eigen-decompose $\Sigma^{-1}$ but cannot produce a $|\Sigma|^{-1}$ on the exponent.

Comment: You need to expand out the exponent with one term in $t^{2}$, one in $t$ and one constant (in fact you don't have to work out the constant term because it'll just get absorbed into the normalising factor). Then complete the square. It might be a little tedious to do but fairly straightforward.

Comment: In your second expression $\boldsymbol{u}^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\boldsymbol{u}$ is just a number. Call it $1/\sigma^{2}$. I think this eigendecomposition stuff is a red herring.

Comment: Actually it feels like $P(t\pmb{u} + \pmb{\mu})$ doesn't even integrate to 1

Comment: Well it won't unless you make it! Just include the appropriate normalising factor $1/(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})$ and it will integrate to 1.

Comment: I have assumed that you want the *conditional* distribution. That you are asking whereabouts on the line a point is likely to be found *given that* it does lie on the line.

Answer (score 1):

With $\mu'=\mu-\mu_{0}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
p(t)&=&\frac{1}{Z}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(tu-\mu'\right)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\left(tu-\mu'\right)\right\}\\
&=& \frac{1}{Z'}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(
\left(u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}u\right)t^{2}-2\left(u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu'\right)t\right)\right\}\\
&=&\frac{1}{Z''}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}u\right)
\left(t-\frac{u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu'}{u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}u}\right)^{2}\right\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the form of a Normal distibution with mean
\begin{equation*}
\frac{u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu'}{u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}u}
\end{equation*}
and variance
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}u}.
\end{equation*}
The normalising factor $Z''$ is of course
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{\frac{u^{T}\Sigma^{-1}u}{2\pi}}.
\end{equation*}